# Configurar llamada con playback en Asterisk

Tags: python, asterisk

Estoy utilizando Asterisk 16.9 con freepbx, aviso que soy novato y lo que tengo es lo poco que he logrado aprender durante estos días. Tenemos un proyecto en el cual tenemos que programar una llamada automática desde asterisk (dejarla programada para X hora) y que llame a una extensión de uno de los integrantes, cuando el integrante responda su extensión tendrá que escuchar la grabación de un bot diciendole los datos del mensaje que le hemos puesto. Casi como hacen los bancos, aseguradoras para recordar las fechas o dar promociones.

La ejecución en mi cabeza va de la siguiente manera:

Tengo mi archivo call file en el cual programo la llamada para X hora especifica de la siguiente manera:

```
 Channel: Local/0123333331@from-internal
 MaxRetries: 2
 Callerid: "Kenny" <0123333331>
 RetryTime: 2000
 WaitTime: 30
 Archive: yes
 Context: from-internal
 Extension: 0123333331
 Priority: 1
```

Esta es una extensión 0123333331 la cual es una extensión PJSIP que he creado desde freepbx en la GUI y por lo que tengo entendido se crea por defecto en el contexto de from-internal que está especificado en extensions.conf.

Entonces voy a mi archivo extensions.conf tengo el siguiente código en el apartado donde se encuentra "from-internal":

```
[from-internal] ; El call file ejecutaria al llamar a la extensión 0123333331 ejecutaría su contexto que seria from-internal
; esto ya estaba por defecto (no las puse yo)
include => from-internal-noxfer
include => from-internal-xfer
include => bad-number ; auto-generated
exten => h,1,Macro(hangupcall)

exten => 012333331,1,Answer ; el call file al llamar haría match con esta instrucción, haciendo que cuando la persona responda escuche esto
exten => 012333331,n,System(scl enable rh-python36 bash) ; en esta parte le estoy diciendo que abra una consola de linux con python 3
exten => 012333331,n,System(python /root/texto_mp3.py) ; luego que ejecute el codigo de python que creé, el cual se conecta con la api gTTS de google para convertir el texto que le mando, en voz por medio del bot y poder generar un archivo .mp3 ya con el texto en voz
exten => 012333331,n,System(ffmpeg -y -i /root/prueba.mp3 -ar 8000 -ac 1 /root/prueba.wav) ; convierto dicho archivo .mp3 en archivo .wav
exten => 012333331,n,Playback(/root/prueba) ; hago que suene en la llamada el archivo prueba.wav que sería la voz del bot diciendo el texto que converti anteriormente a voz a la persona que está escuchando
exten => 012333331,n,Hangup() ; cuelga la llamada
```

El problema que tengo es que el call file funciona perfectamente, es decír, lo programo con el primer código que puse, lo paso a la carpeta de outgoing y la hora especificada llama a la extensión, sin embargo, cuando respondo la llamada no se escucha el archivo .wav que tendría que sonar según lo que programé en extensions.conf, es como si no ejecutara el codigo del contexto que puse abajo en from-internal.

Me imagino que algo estoy entendiendo mal. No entiendo la verdad qué hacer y cómo pueden ver soy super nuevo en esto jaja. Por favor si pudieran ayudarme, lo apreciaría mucho!  Gracias!

El cli de asterisk (asterisk -r) no muestra nada durante la llamada, por eso mismo tengo la duda si enrealidad está leyendo lo del contexto from-internal.
Ya intenté reiniando el servicio de asterisk con systemctl restart asterisk, y con "core reload" desde el cli.

Comment: Pero ¿se generan el mp3 y el wav?, ¿es un mensaje distinto para cada llamada?

Comment: si primero el mp3, y luego se convierte a wav, ya que asterisk solamente lee .wav hasta donde tengo entendido. Es un mensaje igual para todas las llamadas en este caso.

Comment: Si es el mismo mensaje ¿Tiene caso convertir el archivo para cada llamada?. Revisa  los permisos del wav para el usuario de asterisk.

Comment: Perdon creo que no me exoliqué bien, quiero decir, el mensaje que se dirá es diferente ya que el archivo de python envía el menaaje a gtts sacando datos de una base de datos entonces el mensaje va cambiando pero el nombre del archivo es el mismo

Answer (score 0):

En caso que no hayas resuelto tú pregunta, existe una aplicación para Asterisk con FreePBX o Issabel/Elastix que hace lo que necesitas, básicamente cargas una plantilla excel con registros luego grabas un mensaje y el sistema lo programas para que llame desde X horas a los teléfonos que cargaste en la plantilla excel, búscalo como ipnetivr en la web, saludos.